# Dynamic Programming Solution for Activity-selection

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

In `16.1 An activity-selection problem` of `Introduction to Algorithm`, the dynamic programming solution for this problem was given as

> c[i, j] = 0 if S(i, j) is empty
>
> c[i, j] = max { c[i, k] + c[k, j] + 1 } if S(i, j) is not empty

where `S(i, j)` denotes the set of activities that start after activity `a(i)` finishes and that finish before activity `a(j)` starts, and `c[i, j]` denotes the size of an optimal solution for the set `S(i, j)`

However, I am thinking of another simpler solution

```
c[i] = max { c[i - 1], c[f(i)] + 1 }
```

where `f(i)` gives the activity that is compatible with `a(i)` and has the max **finish time and finishes before `a(i)` starts.**

Will this work? If yes, why the author provides this complex solution. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Isn't your solution the same as the Greedy-Activity-Selector algorithm from that chapter?

Comment: No, I don't think this is greedy because it's not making decision beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing many details of designing the dp solution.

1. What is the initial value?
2. What is the base case?
3. what happens if there are several activities compatible with a(i) with same finishing time?

When designing a dp solution, one of the properties needed is [optimal substructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure)

The computing order of a particular state (i.e. c[i]) is important, it can only be computed by its subproblems. Your solution does not meet this requirement, as when you computing c[i], you have to computer c[j] first with j = f(i), let's assume j > i (or even j = i+1) , then you have to compute c[i] before computing c[j]! So c[i] depends on c[j] while c[j] depends on c[i] ==> not correct

Another example very similar to this question is [Matrix chain mutiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication)

You may want to have a look :)

**Edit:**
After seeing you edit the question, then here's my response:

Assuming you can precompute f(i) in reasonable time (which obviously can), your solution is correct as **it IS the greedy solution** as other answers told you.

The reason why it works is quite straight forward, literally speaking,

`until the i-th activity, you either choose activity i (thats the c[f(i)]+1 part) or not choose it (the c[i-1]) part`

You can try to construct a formal proof as well, the correctness of a greedy method can usually be proofed by contradiction (roughly speaking, you can try to see why **it is NOT possible to have a larger set other than c[i-1] if you do not choose activity i, similar for the case that you choose activity i**)

To answer your question about why writer demonstrate the dp solution, I think it's out of programming context, but my thought is the user is trying to demonstrate two different ways to solve a problem, and furthermore to illustrate an idea here: **given a problem which can be solved by greedy method, it can also be solved by dp but IT IS OVERKILLING.**

Then the writer try to help the reader to recognize the difference between Greedy and dp as they are quite similar to a new learner. And that's why the writer first give the DP solution to show the pain, then the greedy solution, lastly a paragraph `Greedy versus DP` in [Page 382](http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=NLngYyWFl_YC&pg=PA371&lpg=PA371&dq=16.1+An+activity-selection+problem+of+Introduction+to+Algorithm&source=bl&ots=BxWpDy-oK9&sig=K_gic0f17lrmhli5i96eXi0jCjw&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ei=AhYMU4eUIomDiQfdooGwAQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=16.1%20An%20activity-selection%20problem%20of%20Introduction%20to%20Algorithm&f=false)

**So TL;DR:  Your solution is correct as it is basically the greedy method to solve the problem, and of course it is much easier than the DP solution given in the book, as this IS the point the book would like to illustrate.**
*A quote from the book at P.382: ...One might be temped to generate a dp solution to a problem when a greedy solution suffices, or one might mistakenly think that a greedy solution suffices...when a dp solution is required...*

Answer (score 2):

> Will this work?

Yes, that will work too.

> why the author provides this complex solution.

That wasn't their proposed solution, but a part of the analysis of the problem. In the next paragraph after the equation you cited the authors say:

> But we would be overlooking another important characteristic of the
>   activity-selection problem that we can use to great advantage.

The final solution (Greedy-Activity-Selector) is similar to yours, but even simpler.

Their point, as I understand it, is that a DP solution can be built almost mechanically (as described in the chapter 15.3), without considering the specifics of that particular problem, but coming up with a better algorithm requires some insight into the problem beyond the optimal substructure.

Your solution relies on the theorem 16.1, but once the theorem is proven, it doesn't make sense to create another DP algorithm, because you already know enough about the problem to create a simpler greedy algorithm.

Comment: Yes, it's the latter case. `f(i)` denotes all the activities that finish before `a(i)` starts. I referenced the chapter here instead of providing too much of details. Actually the `a(i)` should be sorted by the finish times. In the counter example, they are not sorted by the finish times. If you switch `a(1)` and `a(2)`, the algorithm actually works.

What I am wondering is that my solution is much more simpler and it has same running time as the greedy one, it seems the author was deliberately choosing a harder DP solution here.

Comment: @user571470 Do you mean your solution is simpler than the one you cited in the question, or simpler than the final algorithm in the chapter [(image here)](http://i.imgur.com/6e9kLYu.png)? Because the only difference I see between your solution and Greedy-Activity-Selector is that you store all of `c[i]`, and Greedy-Activity-Selector only stores the index of the last activity added to the resulting set.

Comment: I meant it's simpler than the DP one cited in the question. And that's why I didn't mention greedy at all in the question.

Comment: @user571470 That's what I find confusing. You say that the solution the authors provide is too complex, but the algorithm you cite is not *the* solution. Their final solution is the greedy algorithm described in the end of the chapter, the one you didn't mention. And it is essentially your algorithm, but with one further optimization/simplification: not to store all intermediate answers and process only those activities that are compatible with the current partial solution. I updated the answer.

Comment: @user571470 You also may ask, why are they comparing an overly complex DP solution with a good greedy solution, instead of comparing the best DP solution with the best greedy solution? Is that what you meant? I edited the answer to address that too.