# Counting all valid solutions for Activity-selection

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, counting, greedy

How can we count all possible valid solutions  for a given Activity-selection Problem using the dynamic approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976739/dynamic-programming-solution-for-activity-selection) ?

Details:
Let's say there are 6 jobs with given start and finish times
 start[]  =  {1, 3, 0, 5, 8, 5};
 finish[] =  {2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 9};

One solution is {0, 1, 3, 4}

I don't want the solutions. I just want to count all possible solutions.

Please someone help!!

Comment: When you say "valid solution," do you mean "feasible schedule" or "maximum schedule?"

Comment: Let's say that if we try all possible ways to reach at a solution, a decision tree will be formed. We might reach nodes of the tree where we can clearly see that we might miss deadline of one of the jobs. In such a case we have to chose some other tree node to continue scheduling. I want to count all possible nodes of such a tree.